# ngRoute causing blank screen in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm just getting acquainted with AngularJS with a very basic structure and I'm getting blank screens with no errors showing up in console.

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="mySite">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**/templates/hello.html**

```html
<h2>Welcome {{helloTo.title}} to the world of Angular!</h2>
```

**app.js**

```js
var mySite = angular.module("mySite", ['ngRoute', 'controllers']);

mySite.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/hello.html',
        controller: 'helloController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }
]);
```

**controllers.js**

```js
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

controllers.controller("helloController", function($scope) {
 $scope.helloTo = {};
 $scope.helloTo.title = "TestSite";
});
```

I should also mention I'm running this code on an local test apache server. To execute the code I'm pointing my browser to: http://127.0.0.1/

Comment: What build tool are you using ? `gulp` ?

Comment: Can you confirm that your server is behaving as expected? Are you getting your index.html file served when you hit http://127.0.0.1? If not, this is an Apache config problem. Your Angular code looks fine.

Comment: @Shaun Scovil I am getting my index.html data when I go to 127.0.0.1, but nothing in the view is added. I also checked the GET requests that happen in the header of index.html, all report code 200.

Comment: @jimmyobonyo I'm not using a build tool at the moment, I'm just trying to do some basic code with angular in a test environment.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem at http://plnkr.co ?

Comment: Here is an example plunk I created for another SO answer related to ngRoute: http://plnkr.co/edit/nSsagK1Y04akNJyMToah

Comment: @ShaunScovil interesting, considering it is working over here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CM2VPOXc59P7vt6K7lib then I'm putting the blame on the apache server here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suspect one or more of your script files is not loading. Check the resources tab in Chrome inspector to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is totally valid, and you should check if the hello.html is loaded successfully in Google chrome developer tool panel at network tab.

Here is a duplicated version from all your code, and it works well.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bWkJpEziz1eHkv5VdTv4?p=preview

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="mySite">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$http` service to your controller ,test also to note check if your controller is being called by using angular inspector tools ie http://ng-inspector.org

Comment: There's no need for adding the $http service in this case. That service is used for making http requests; ngRoute does that to load the view template, but nothing in the controller is making a request.

Comment: tried out that extension, doesn't show the controller being called at all under the root scope